# « Je me vois mal prendre le dessert au derrière » ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, locutions, ellipse

> — Voici une généreuse portion de poutine !
>  — Je me vois mal prendre le dessert *au derrière*...
>  — Aucun dessert n'étant placé derrière, il serait difficile en effet de l'y prendre...

Que signifie « (prendre le dessert) au derrière » dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un cas d'expression de la *postériorité temporelle*. On trouve la locution prépositive *au [derrière](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/derri%C3%A8re) de* au TLFi :

> *Allez-vous manger votre fromage **au derrière de** votre viande ?* (Renard, *Journal*, 1894, p. 709)

Ça signifie *après quelque chose*. Mais Grevisse commente l'exemple au *LBU* en indiquant « mais il faut ajouter que c'est la servante Ragotte qui parle » et ajoute un autre exemple : "*Elle [c'est encore
Ragotte] donne à Philippe sa soupe et un morceau de pain « AU DERRIÈRE »*". L'emploi des guillemets lui fait dire que ce serait dans cet exemple très précis « manifestement » du *français populaire bourguignon* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 1058 R). Plus généralement l'emploi de *derrière* pour *après* est [attestée](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/derri%C3%A8re) chez Hugo (1823 ; TLFi, DHLF). Ce sens s'est développé bien après le sens spatial de la préposition.

Il arrive *fréquemment* d'omettre le régime des locutions prépositives quand il est facile à déduire ou que l'on vient d'en traiter, et quand leur dernier élément est *de*, il sera lui aussi régulièrement omis (LBU14 § 1040).

---

La locution *au derrière de* signifierait *après (quelque chose)*, ici après la poutine (on ne pense pas avoir l'appétit pour un dessert) ; on a omis le *de*.